# Custom claim missing from saml response with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, okta, idp

I am using Azure AD as identity provider for Okta, with SAML2 protocol. I am able to login just fine. However, I want to send the user's phonenumber from Azure AD to Okta, but Im having problems.

I tried following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization) to add a custom claim, and I added one with these values:

- Name: mobilePhone
- Value: user.telephonenumber (the only one related to phonenumber I could find)
- Namespace: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims

I have also added my phonenumber on my profile (Home > Company > Users - All Users > Me - profile) in Azure Active Directory. However, when I login and check the SAML response using my extension, the claim for mobilePhone is nowhere to be found. Why is it missing? Chances are I added my phonenumber on the wrong places, but shouldnt there be an empty claim somewhere?

Comment: "but shouldnt there be an empty claim somewhere?"

If the value for the attribute can not be retrieved from the user , no related SAML attribute must be sent.

Comment: To ask my question in a different way.. The attributes are missing from the response. Could I have accidentally configured my request for the response in such a way that they are not sent, or is the problem on the Identity Provider side, for not sending the required attribute?

Comment: By default , SAMLv2 does not allow to request attributes in the response when sending a SAML AuthnRequest. It's a mis-configuration on the Azure AD IdP side, either the attribute is named differently  or it's not present in the user identity. You may use Azure AD commandlet to retrieve all attributes for this specific user entry.